# Creating a shortcode with an image and text aligned at the middle

Tags: css, wordpress, shortcode

How can I create a WordPress shortcode that enables you to add an image with text next to it, aligned to the middle of the image?

```
[       ]
[       ]
[ IMAGE ] My Text (aligned in middle)
[       ]
[       ]
```

Now here is my code but it does not execute well -

**Execution in wordpress:**

```
[contactIcon]here I add my image and text next to each other[/contactIcon]
```

**function.php**

```
function contactIcon($atts, $content = null) {
    $content = do_shortcode($content);
    return '<div class="contactIcon"><img src="' . $content . '" alt="icon" /><span class="contactHeader">' . $caption . '</span></div><div style="clear:both"></div>';
}
add_shortcode('contactIcon','contactIcon');
```

Note: the reason why I want to do this is because in WordPress, when you add an image and text next to it, it does not align to the middle and I have to add a clear div to the bottom each time.

Comment: How does it comes `$content` is the source of the image? What's wrong with adding a clear div? What's the CSS for this elements? . . . Off-topic: [about salutations in SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/185667).

Comment: because I would like to create a shortcode for it. Not all people know about clearing divs...i am not the only one who will be working on this site

Comment: This CSS alignment has been answered here in [so], just research for it. I suppose, if you are inserting the clear div inside the code, no user has to do it when writing the shortcode.